# Is it possible to create an extension method that can be used in an sql query?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I have an application that draws elements from a database when a search button is clicked. I need to update it so that I can find elements that have a specific `Substring` exactly 6 places into the string. For example, I need to find 111-2233-44-555 by looking for 33 at the 6th and 7th places. My first instinct was to create an extension method for the string class so that I could say something like this:

```
Dim example As String = "111-2233-44-555"
If example.HasYear(33) Then
  'Do Something'
End If
```

And this worked perfectly. Here's the method I made:

```
Public Module StringExtensionMethods
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Finds the year in a competition number of format XXX-XXXX-XX-XXX
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="pstrCompNum">The competition number to find the year in</param>
    <Extension()>
    Public Function HasYear(ByVal pstrCompNum As String, ByVal pstrCompYear As String) As Boolean
        Try

            Dim testString As String = pstrCompNum

            Debug.Print(testString)
            Dim testSubstring As String = testString.Substring(6, 2)
            If testSubstring.Equals(pstrCompYear) Then
                Return True
            End If
            Return False

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
End Module
```

But a problem arises when I try to use this method in an `SQL` query. Rightfully so, since `HasYear()` isn't related to `SQL` in any way whatsoever. Here's the query I want to execute:

```
Dim o = From c In myContext.Competitions.Include("CodeJusticeBranches").Include("CodeJusticeLocations").Include("CodeCompetitionTypes").Include("CodePositionTypes").Include("CompetitionPositions") _
                        Where (pstrCompNum Is Nothing OrElse c.comp_number = pstrCompNum) _
                        And (pstrCompYear Is Nothing OrElse c.comp_number.HasYear(strYear) = True) _
                        And (pstrCompTypeId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodeCompetitionTypes.code_ct_id = CInt(pstrCompTypeId)) _
                        And (pstrBranchId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodeJusticeBranches.code_branch_id = CInt(pstrBranchId)) _
                        And (pstrPosTypeId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodePositionTypes.code_pos_type_id = CInt(pstrPosTypeId)) _
                        Order By c.comp_number _
                        Select c
```

I get the error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean HasYear (System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

So what I'm looking for is essentially a way to make an extension method that can be used in an `SQL` query. Any ideas?

Comment: Many framework methods don't work in LINQ because the SQL server doesn't support them. You should only include the methods which are supported in your query, and then put `ToList()` to execute the query, then filter the resulting data with your unsupported methods.

Comment: `SubString` should be translatable to SQL, so you could simply not use the `HasYear` function.

Comment: Good idea, I've tried it and it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like what @djv posted, but I've decided to try out Andrew Morton's suggestion, to just omit the HasYear() altogether. I ended up using this:

```
Dim k = From c In myContext.Competitions.Include("CodeJusticeBranches").Include("CodeJusticeLocations").Include("CodeCompetitionTypes").Include("CodePositionTypes").Include("CompetitionPositions") _
                        Where (pstrCompNum Is Nothing OrElse c.comp_number = pstrCompNum) _
                        And (pstrCompYear Is Nothing OrElse c.comp_number.Substring(6, 2) = pstrCompYear) _
                        And (pstrCompTypeId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodeCompetitionTypes.code_ct_id = CInt(pstrCompTypeId)) _
                        And (pstrBranchId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodeJusticeBranches.code_branch_id = CInt(pstrBranchId)) _
                        And (pstrPosTypeId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodePositionTypes.code_pos_type_id = CInt(pstrPosTypeId)) _
                        Order By c.comp_number _
                        Select c
```

Notice the line `And (pstrCompYear Is Nothing OrElse c.comp_number.Substring(6, 2) = pstrCompYear)`

This solved my problem very simply.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include custom functions in your LINQ. It must be convertable to SQL so your extension method doesn't qualify. Just execute your query with supported where clauses, then tack on your custom queries after.

```vb
Dim o = (
    From c In myContext.Competitions.Include("CodeJusticeBranches").Include("CodeJusticeLocations").Include("CodeCompetitionTypes").Include("CodePositionTypes").Include("CompetitionPositions")
    Where (pstrCompNum Is Nothing OrElse c.comp_number = pstrCompNum) _
    And (pstrCompTypeId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodeCompetitionTypes.code_ct_id = CInt(pstrCompTypeId)) _
    And (pstrBranchId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodeJusticeBranches.code_branch_id = CInt(pstrBranchId)) _
    And (pstrPosTypeId Is Nothing OrElse c.CodePositionTypes.code_pos_type_id = CInt(pstrPosTypeId))
    Order By c.comp_number Select c).ToList().
    Where(Function(c) c.pstrCompYear Is Nothing OrElse c.comp_number.HasYear(strYear))
```

Comment: I like this, but I saw what @Andrew Morton wrote and I've decided to go with that. It ended up being the better solution in the eyes of my supervisors as well. Thank you for your answer however, any knowledge I can get into different solutions is welcome (I'm a beginner programmer), and I'll absolutely find a use for this somewhere down the road.

Comment: @BrenCou in this case, maybe `Substring` works. But there are cases when your function is more complex and you can't / don't want to convert it to SQL. Then my method works. If performance doesn't suffer too much, you may want to use your function for readability / understandability because the intention of `HasYear` is more obvious than `Substring(6, 2) = ... `.

Comment: I agree with the readability part. HasYear is more intuitive, but we've created some good documentation for the use of Substring, so I think we should be good. Also, that's what I meant when I said I'll be able to find a use for it. There's no telling what problems I'm going to need to solve and your solution will def come in handy.